# Pegar nome e sobrenome de uma string

Tags: javascript

Estou precisando pegar o nome e sobrenome de uma string. Por exemplo, se o nome completo for:

```
Renan Rodrigues Moraes
```

preciso pegar apenas `Renan Rodrigues`. Sei o que devo fazer porém não sei como fazer.  No caso do nome ser `Renan de Assis` seria interessante retornar `Renan de Assis`.

Sei o que devo fazer porém não sei como fazer.

A ideia principal é contar dois espaços, a partir do segundo não mostrar nada. Alguém tem uma sugestão para extrair isso da string?

Comment: Separa sua string por espaços e pega a 1 e 2 parte.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes usar `.split(' ')` para criar uma array. Depois usando o `.slice(0, 2)` crias uma cópia só com os dois primeiros. Por fim, se quiseres de volta uma string, podes fazer `.join(' ')`:

```
'Renan Rodrigues Moraes'.split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ');
```

#### exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bo2ropp1/

No caso de haver nomes com `de` ou `do` como por exemplo `Renan de Assis` poderias usar regex assim ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/mxf63c21/)), ou verificar se a segunda palavra começa com letra grande assim ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/6ezhLo0f/)), assim:

```
function nome(str) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    if (arr[1][0].toUpperCase() != arr[1][0]) arr.splice(1, 1);
    return arr.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
}
```

De qualquer maneira precisas criar alguns exemplos e testar para teres certeza que funciona como queres...

E para manter esses `de`/`do` poderias fazer assim:

```
function nome(str) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    var keep = arr[1][0].toUpperCase() != arr[1][0];
    return arr.slice(0, keep ? 3 : 2).join(' ');
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ezhLo0f/1/

Comment: E no caso do nome ser `Renan de Assis`? como ficaria ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues nesse caso queres só `Renan Assis` de retorno?

Comment: O interessante seria `Renan de Assis`

Comment: @RenanRodrigues estou a ver, juntei isso na resposta.

Comment: O problema é garantir que no cadastro o `de`, `da` ou `do` não sejam escritos com letra maiúscula. Pensei em considerar a quantidade de caracteres mas daria problemas em nomes como `Antônio de Sá`. Talvez sua função possa realmente ignorar as condições `de`, `da` e `do` já que são únicas, acredito eu.

Comment: @Gerep é verdade. Por isso referí na resposta _"criar alguns exemplos e testar para teres certeza que funciona como queres"_. É possivel fazer uma versão mais complexa mas sem saber mais de onde os dados vêm e possiveis formatos acho que a resposta acerta no que é pedido.

Comment: @Sergio Entendi. Eu acabei adicionando uma reposta com uma solução mais direta e menos dinâmica.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode dar um split nos espaços em branco da string, depois pegar apenas o primeiro e segundo elemento do array:

```
var nome = "Renan Rodrigues Moraes";
var tmp = nome.split(" ");
nome = tmp[0] + " " + tmp[1];
```

**Edit:**

Porém você vai precisar de um tratamento especial para casos onde o nome for tipo "João da Silva", pois nesse caso ficaria "João da".

Comment: Como ficaria com tratamento ?

Comment: while ? for ? teria como adicionar em seu exemplo ?

Comment: Se você estiver buscando do banco o nome completo, a melhor maneira é sempre diferenciar as duas informações, gravando em colunas diferentes ( nome / sobrenome ).

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @Sergio resolve esse problema.

Answer (score 3):

Levando em consideração [meu comentário na resposta do Sérgio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125559/pegar-nome-e-sobrenome-de-uma-string/125562?noredirect=1#comment262022_125562)...

*O problema é garantir que no cadastro o de, da ou do não sejam escritos com letra maiúscula. Pensei em considerar a quantidade de caracteres mas daria problemas em nomes como Antônio de Sá. Talvez sua função possa realmente ignorar as condições de, da e do já que são únicas, acredito eu.*

eis uma possível solução:

```
function nome(str) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    if(arr[1].toLowerCase() == 'de' || arr[1].toLowerCase() == 'da' || arr[1].toLowerCase() == 'do') {
        return arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2]
    } else {
        return arr[0] + " " + arr[1]
    }
}

console.log(nome('Renan de Rodrigues Moraes'));
console.log(nome('Renan DE Rodrigues Moraes'));
console.log(nome('Antônio De Sá Moreira'));
```

Comment: `+1`, mas não devia ser `return arr[0] + " " + arr[1] + " " + arr[2]` em vêz de `return arr[0] + " " + arr[2]`?

Comment: @Sergio Nesse caso o `arr[1]` seria o `de`, `da` ou `do`, acredito que o objetivo seja ignorar eles?

Comment: A ideia é manter esses também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125559/pegar-nome-e-sobrenome-de-uma-string/125562?noredirect=1#comment261750_125562

Comment: Sugestão: `['de', 'da', 'do', 'das', 'dos'].indexOf(arr[1].toLowerCase()) > -1`. E também entendi que é para manter. Ou seja, retornar as três primeiras posições se houver um conector, senão retornar as duas primeiras.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar **JS Split** para pegar o nome e sobrenome da String a partir de seus espaços.

Ficaria assim:

```
var nomeCompleto = "Renan Rodrigues Moraes";
var nome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[0];
var sobrenome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Desenterrando tópico…

Precisei disso agora, precisava do primeiro e último nome, ficou assim:

```
    var nomeCompleto = "Renan Rodrigues Moraes";
    var nome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[0];
    var qtdnome = nomeCompleto.split(" ").length;
    var sobrenome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[qtdnome-1]; 
    console.log(qtdnome)
    console.log(nome)
    console.log(sobrenome)
```

Answer (score -2):

Precisava do primeiro e último nome, ficou assim:

```js
function nome(nameShort) {
    var nameShort = nameShort.split(' ');
     nameShort = nameShort.slice(0,1) + ' ' + nameShort.slice(-1);
      return nameShort;
}

console.log(nome('Renan de Rodrigues Moraes'));
```

Answer (score -6):

Pessoal ta complicando demais:

```
var nomeCompleto = "Renan Rodrigues Moraes";
var nome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[0];
var ultimoNome = nomeCompleto.split(" ")[nomeCompleto.split(" ").length -1];
```

Comment: Amigão, até para exercício pessoal. Explica a logica de funcionamento desse código e explique também porque usar três splits e não só um split.

Comment: @AugustoVasques se eu entendi direito, ele deu um exemplo de como o pessoal complica demais (ao menos a 1a frase e o código indicam isso)